# How to retrieve rows in dataframe as strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have probably stupid question for you guys but I cannot find a working solution so far to my problem. I have a data frame provided via automatic input and I am transforming this data as such (not really relevant for my question):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = int(input())
matrix =[]
for n in range(n+1): # loop as long as expected # rows to be input
    new_row = input() # get new row input
    new_row = list(new_row.split(",")) # make it a list
    matrix.append(new_row)   #update the matrix

mat = pd.DataFrame(data=matrix[1:], index=None, columns=matrix[0])
mat.iloc[:,1] = pd.to_numeric(mat.iloc[:,1])
mat.iloc[:,2] = pd.to_numeric(mat.iloc[:,2])
mat.iloc[:,1] = round(mat.iloc[:,1] / mat.iloc[:,2])
mat2 = mat[['state', 'population']].head(5)
mat2['population'] = mat2['population'].astype(int)
mat2 = mat2.sort_values(by=['population'], ascending=False)
mat2 = mat2.to_string(index=False, header=False)

print(mat2)
```

the answer I am getting is equal to:

```
   New York  354
    Florida  331
 California  240
   Illinois  217
      Texas  109
```

Nicely formated etc, however I need to retrieve my data in string format as:

```
New York 354
Florida 331
California 240
Illinois 217
Texas 109
```

I have already tried changing the ending of my code to:

```
#mat2 = mat2.to_string(index=False, header=False)

print(mat2.iloc[1,:])
```

to retrieve e.g. first row, but then console returns:

```
state         Florida
population        331
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

How can I simply access the data from my cells and format it in string format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `mat2 = mat2.to_string(index=False, header=False)`, `mat2` becomes a string you can transform to your liking. For instance, you could do:

```
>>> lines = mat2.split('\n')
>>> without_format = [line.strip() for line in lines]
>>> without_format
    ['New York  354',
     'Florida  331',
     'California  240',
     'Illinois  217',
     'Texas  109']
```

Where `.strip()` will remove any whitespace before or after the string.